# How to reuse variables in cgo？

Tags: c, linux, go, cgo

I use GO code build a so file, and call it from go. at begin, i want to do some init job, so make sure the go call the shared library can reuse some variable. for example:
**main.go**

```
package main

import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

var (
    globalConfig string
)

func main() {

}

//export search
func search() {
    fmt.Println(globalConfig)
}

//export start
func start() {
    // just keep running to keep globalConfig in RAM
    go forever()

    quitChannel := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(quitChannel, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    <-quitChannel
}

func forever() {
    v := "global value"
    globalConfig = v
    for {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println(globalConfig)
    }
}
```

and then generate the shared library.

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o libsdk.so main.go
```

call the shared lib.
**cgo1.go**

```
package main

/*
first step: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="xxx sopath xxx"
*/

// #include "libsdk.h"
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -lsdk
import "C"

func main() {
    C.start()
    // C.search()
}
```

**cgo2.go**

```
package main

/*
first step: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="xxx sopath xxx"
*/

// #include "libsdk.h"
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -lsdk
import "C"

func main() {
    // C.start()
    C.search()
}
```

and then the output first get the global value, the the second is null.

shouldn't shared lib share memory?

Comment: You have two `main` packages, which means you have two separate programs, which means: no, the shared libraries will not share memory.

Comment: Shared libraries do not mean sharing memory between processes. You also cannot safely import a go shared library into a go program, because you then have multiple go runtimes in the same process.

Comment: @JimB I tried to use pointers to exchange contexts, which seems to work well.

Comment: @torek sorry, It is just example. i made two package for the main function. I think this question can be solve by define a pointer to exchange context in every api calls.